# Python odeint, parameter

Tags: python, arrays, parameters, odeint

I'm trying to solve a simple equation: `dM/dr = r*p(r)` in python.

I have the values of `p` at certain values of `r`:

`p(0)=1`, `p(1)=3`, `p(2)=5`, `p(3)=7`, `p(4)=9`, `p(5)=11`.

I tried using the following code but I get the error

> The size of the array returned by func (6) does not match the size of
>   y0 (1).

I think the problem is that I'm not matching the `p` values with the `r` values correctly. There should only be one initial condition since I am only trying to solve one equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

r = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
p = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11])

def deriv (z, r, data):
    M = r*p
    return M

init = np.array([0])
soln = integrate.odeint(deriv, init, p, (r,), full_output=True)
print soln
```

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this error because the size of `init` does *not* match the size of the array returned by `deriv()`.

To solve the problem, change the following line

```
init = np.array([0])
```

to

```
init = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

For more examples on using 'odeint', see:
http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/numpy_scipy_ordinary_differential_equations.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html